# Почему модераторы удалили мой вопрос участнику?

Tags: discussion

Владимир Жеребцов задал здесь вопрос, почему у Гоголя в "Вечерах на хуторе близ Диканьки" отчество "Кириллович" написано с одной буквой Л: [Одна Л в "Вечерах на хуторе"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/467038/%d0%9e%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%9b-%d0%b2-%d0%92%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%85-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%85%d1%83%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b5/467057?noredirect=1#comment483929_467057) Я спросил его, во всех ли изданиях так (предполагая, что это могла быть элементарная опечатка). Мой вопрос удалили. Я хочу понять: почему?

Comment: Вопрос к участнику не может размещаться в рубрике "Ответ", его место в _комментариях_ (окно "Комментировать" при исходном вопросе или ответе на него).

Comment: @Alex_ander Для комментирования необходимо 50 баллов.

Answer (score 4):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
..................................................................................................................................
Источник: https://rus.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers

Для вопросов не про русский язык, а про разбирательства есть специальный сайт: https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Значит, уточнять заданные вопросы здесь нельзя... Так и запишем!

Comment: Можно, но не ответом.

Answer (score 2):

Этот вопрос тоже будет удалён с раздела [Русский язык](https://rus.stackexchange.com/), так как не по тематике сайта, но вы можете увидеть его его на [Мете](https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/), сообществе для обсуждения сайта и его устройства.

Ответ может быть удалён решением модератора, я и Aer, (наши полномочия можно распознать по ромбику возле никнейма) или кворумом из 3 опытных участников, последнее и произошло в вашем случае.

Причиной удаления по всей видимости послужило то, что вы вместо ответа написали комментарий. Я понимаю, что у вас пока нет возможности оставлять комментарии, но после набора 50 пунктов рейтинга такая возможность у вас появится. Сделать это совсем не сложно, каждый голос, данный за ваш ответ или вопрс даёт вам +10 к рейтингу. Пока что я восстановил ваше сообщение, преобразовав его в комментарий.

Ну. и просьба к участникам сообщества. Если вы видите, что новичок с рейтингом меньше 50 вместо ответа даёт комментарий, отправляйте тревогу модераторам, тогда мы сможем сделать преобразование, не отпугнув нового участника.

Comment: Каюсь, запамятовала, что для комментирования нужно 50 баллов. Но две тревоги модераторам мною были посланы! P. S. Поправьте, пожалуйста, в своем ответе: за вопрос — тоже +10.